# What will happen same role persons are trying to change the warehouse size at same time in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, warehouse

Two persons with same roles (sysadmin) trying to change warehouse size ata same time? Which user instructions will execute first?

Comment: It's hard to get it at exactly the same time, there will always be a small difference in ms in between, but I believe both will change the WH size as they will be executing one after another.

Comment: Agree with @Sergiu, dont think there will be any priority as such. Both requests will be serviced on first come first serve basis or which ever request a particular snowflake connection is able to execute first and the one serviced last (or that finishes executing last) will dictate final warehouse size.

Answer (score 0):

like every one else, there is no same time...

But also the warehouse resize is handled by the service layer, so there is an order there. I would assume the resize command for the second would be ignored, as it is "already in the process of a resize to the same size" if the sizes are different I would assume/hope the "last wins" but also could see the second getting an error with a resize is underway.

This is all based on the fact, that a resize leave the existing servers running while they complete, and starts queued/new queries on the new servers. Which firstly has to be spun up. So this is really a slow (in computer time) operation. And thus it's not a wild +1 type thing, as you explicitly set the size to something.